# Differences between types in Python and their visibility

Tags: python, function, exception, types

I just wondering, what differences between next two functions (Python 3.x)

```
def first_example ():
    counter = 0
    def inc_counter ():
        counter += 1
    for i in range (10):
            inc_counter ()

def second_example ():
    counter = [0]
    def inc_counter ():
        counter[0] += 1
    for i in range (10):
            inc_counter ()
```

First function throw exception about referenced before assignment, but the second function works well. Could somebody explain me, why python remember arrays, but not integers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are assigning to the `counter` name in the first nested function, making it a local variable.

In the second example, you never assign to `counter` directly, making it a free variable, which the compiler rightly connected to the `counter` in the parent function. You never rebind the name, you are only altering the list `counter` refers to.

Use the `nonlocal` keyword to mark `counter` as a free variable:

```
def first_example ():
    counter = 0
    def inc_counter ():
        nonlocal counter
        counter += 1
    for i in range (10):
        inc_counter()
```

Comment: Thanks! Nonlocal - is what I am looking! Just started to learn python ))

Answer (score 3):

Variables captured by inner functions (aka "closures") can't be assigned to, unless you explicitly mark them `global` or `nonlocal`.

In the first example, since you're trying to assign, `counter` is taken to refer to an inner local variable, not the outer variable. This inner variable is referenced before assignment, which is an error.

In the second example you are not assigning to the variable, you're calling `__getitem__` on it to do the index lookup. So that's OK, `counter` refers to the outer variable.

Answer (score 1):

In the first example, your intent is to change `counter` to point to a different object (the integer 1 since it starts at 0).

In the second example, `counter` remains pointing to the same object: the list. An *element* of the list is changed. No assignment to `counter` occurs.

The first is not allowable without (in Python 3) declaring `counter` nonlocal. In Python 2 it is not allowable in any circumstances. The assignment `+=` causes `counter` to be a local variable to the inner function. Since it hasn't been assigned a value in that scope, attempting to use it (as `+=` *also* does) causes Python to complain about that.

Answer (score 1):

In Python, a variable is created the first time you assign to it within a function.  In your first example, `counter` is assigned inside `inc_counter`, since writing

```
counter += 1
```

is like writing

```
counter = counter + 1
```

so a new variable called counter is created within that scope.

In your second example, you are only accessing the counter variable, not assigning it, so no new variable is created.